# signer attachments from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I am looking for a way to identify signer attachments that come back from the DocuSign SOAP api method RequestDocumentPDFsEx. Basically, I just need to know how to identify what is an attachment added by the signer and what was not an attachment (i.e., included in the envelope when our system sent it). I recall that at one time the DocumentID property was an empty string for attachments, but that doesn't appear to be the case, as DocuSign is sending those attachments PDFs back with an ID.

Comment: I'm trying to find out on this, not sure if there's a way to identify which is which (i.e. which is an envelope document and which was a signer attachment).  You might have to do it by filename...

Comment: Here's one method:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954749/extracting-attachments-from-signer-attachment-tabs