# Extracting Attachments from Signer Attachment Tabs

Tags: docusignapi

We have created a new template with option to add Attachments using Signer Attachment tabs.

Please let us know how we can programmatically retrieve the Attached files from the envelope using API, we tried using RequestDocumentPDFs() method, but it doesn’t provide us to which “Signer Attachment” tab the document belongs to, since we have multiple “Signer Attachment” tabs.

Ex.
Option A (Checkbox 1 tab) – If the user selects, we will ask “Signer Attachment 1” tab to upload the related document. 
Option B (Checkbox 2 tab) – If the user selects, we will ask “Signer Attachment 2” tab to upload the related document. 
Option C (Checkbox 3 tab) – If the user selects, we will ask “Signer Attachment 3” tab to upload the related document.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that DocuSign gives you a way to programmatically correlate an attached file with the specific Attachment tab that was used to supply the attachment.  However, in the specific scenario that you describe it seems like you could get the info you need ***not*** by evaluating the attached document, but by instead evaluating the checkbox tabs:

- If **Option A** (*Checkbox 1* tab) is selected, then the attachment supplied by the signer correlates to *Signer Attachment 1* tab.
- If **Option B** (*Checkbox 2* tab) is selected, then the attachment
  supplied by the signer correlates to *Signer Attachment 2* tab.
- If **Option C** (*Checkbox 3* tab) is selected, then the attachment
  supplied by the signer correlates to *Signer Attachment 3* tab.

This approach would suffice for the (simple) scenario that you describe, but obviously would be insufficient in cases where you are collecting multiple attachments in various places throughout the envelope.